# Different Behaviour of Grid.RowDefinition at runtime and at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

suppose I have a grid like below:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <converters:MultiplyHeightByThreeConverter x:Key="multiplyHeightByThreeConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=rowPinCode, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource multiplyHeightByThreeConverter}}"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="rowPinCode" Height="Auto" />
        .....
        .....
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    .....
    .....    

</Grid>
```

Here is my Converter Code :

```
public class MultiplyHeightByThreeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (((double)value) * 3);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

At Design time I get the expected Output :

[image]

But at Runtime I don't get that row :

[image]

I have also found the reason for that :

I kept a breakpoint on converter's Convert Method's opening bracket and found that value of `value parameter` is `0.00`

How do I solve the problem?

I also tried to use `Height` instead of `ActualHeight` but then I get error because it cannot convert `Auto` to `Double`

**Update :**

```
<Page x:Class="WPF_Client.Pages.Masters.Single.Ledger"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:Self="clr-namespace:WPF_Client"
      xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPF_Client.HelperClasses"
      xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Data;assembly=Data"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="760" d:DesignWidth="1366"
      Title="Ledger" DataContext="{StaticResource mainWindowViewModel}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection" Source="{Binding GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects}" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CreditDebitsCollection" Source="{Binding CreditDebits}" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentLedger}">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Name" />
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DockPanel>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="Group" />
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Items}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedGroupIDinLedger, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
                      SelectedValuePath="GroupID" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName">
                    <ComboBox.Resources>
                        <CompositeCollection x:Key="Items">
                            <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Background="#FF2A2A2A" Foreground="White">
                                <Grid TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.Children>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Group Name" />
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Effect" />
                                    </Grid.Children>
                                </Grid>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection}}" />
                        </CompositeCollection>

                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.Children>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                                </Grid.Children>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.Resources>
                </ComboBox>
            </DockPanel>

            <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Opening Balance" />
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding OpeningBalance}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4" Margin="10,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Items}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedCreditDebitIDinLedger, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
                      SelectedValuePath="CreditDebitID" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Symbol">
                <ComboBox.Resources>
                    <CompositeCollection x:Key="Items">
                        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Background="#FF2A2A2A" Foreground="White">
                            <Grid TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.Children>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Value" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Symbol" />
                                </Grid.Children>
                            </Grid>
                        </ComboBoxItem>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CreditDebitsCollection}}" />
                    </CompositeCollection>

                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Master_CreditDebits}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.Children>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Symbol}" />
                            </Grid.Children>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.Resources>
            </ComboBox>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Header="Credit Limits" 
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.CreditLimitsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                           Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Credit Days" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding CreditDays}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Credit Limit" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding CreditLimit}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Header="Bank Details"
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.BankDetailsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                           Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="A/c No." />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding BankAccountNo}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Branch" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding BranchName}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="BSR Code" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding BSRCode}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>

        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.15*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <!--Here is the problem part-->

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Header="General Details"
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.GeneralDetailsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                           Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=rowPinCode, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource multiplyHeightByThreeConverter}}" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition x:Name="rowPinCode" Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Address" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Pincode" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding PINCode}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="City" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <ComboBox />
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="State" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <ComboBox />
                    </DockPanel>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Header="Contact Details"
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ContactDetailsVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                           Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">


                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Contact Person" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ContactPerson}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Phone No." />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />

                        <Grid>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DataContext.TelephoneNo1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DataContext.TelephoneNo2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Email Address" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddress}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="Website" />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Website}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>

            <GroupBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Header="Tax Information"
                      Visibility="{Binding DataContext.TaxInformationVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                           Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibilityConverter}}">

                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="PAN / IT No." />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding PANCardOrITNo}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Sales Tax No." />
                    <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text=":" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SalesTaxNo}"/>
                    </DockPanel>

                </Grid>

            </GroupBox>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Page>
```

**Update 2:**

After your suggestions :

At Design Time:

[image]

At Runtime :

[image]

Comment: why -1? Isn't it asked properly? Does this question have answer anywhere else?

Comment: I think your DockPanel with LastChildFill="True" and not having anought space somewhere in visual layout prevents rows to occupy the height. Isn't it easier to use '*' and '10' (for indents) everywhere in row definitions, lay all elements as they are and then specify row index and VerticalAlignent for every element?

Comment: I tried your sample project with the converter (with ActualHeight), everything works and the Adress is 3x height of Pincode row as in Design so at the Runtime. Don't know what troubles are you experiencing.

Comment: Yes that works in sample but does not work in my project. So, I changed the height of both rows to auto. And then I just tried to implement the same logic to the height of the textBox corresponding to Another textbox. And now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need converter. In case you want first row to be thrice of second row, you can give relative width using `3*`.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
   <RowDefinition x:Name="rowPinCode" Width="Auto" Height="*" />
   .....
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using row definitions like mentioned above works completely fine at my end. Definition's declaration:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    <RowDefinition x:Name="rowPinCode" Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="5" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, there was a mistake in my XAML code. RowDefinition does not have a Width property. It is Height instead of Width in my XAML. And I don't want to use * sized Rows. So, I have used Converter.

Comment: I don't want to use * sizing is because my Visual Tree is such that if I use your above code then it will give me the height of 1st and 2nd row same though I specify 3* for 1st row and * for 2nd row.

Comment: No, it shouldn't unless you harcoding child's height to some fixed values. Post complete XAML code to reproduce issue you mentioning.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please see the comment in Update's code where problem resides.

Comment: Works fine at my end. I copied only problematic XAML to my sample. I have added snapshot and row definitions in my answer.

Comment: can you please try the full page code that I posted in my question? It's not working on my end.

Comment: I have updated my question with the images of Designtime and Runtime after trying 3* and *.

Comment: I cannot try your posted code because it won't compile at my end because of lack of some `StaticResources`. Try to break down your problem. Either post the small working sample replicating your issue OR you need to break down to get exact problem because what i proposed in answer works. Problem lies somwhere in your code.

Comment: I have created a sample project. Have a look at it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0beXNTcHJyUVdVRk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I got it to work. For solution please see the comments in question.